# Show apps on top of the lock screen

Tags: node.js, windows, uwp, electron, windows-10

I'm building an app using *[Electron](https://electronjs.org)*. And I really want to recreate what UWP apps can do. UWP apps can get shown on top of the lock screen. How can I achieve that using *[Electron](https://electronjs.org)*/*[NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/)*?

I tried to do this, but it didn't work:

```
const mainWindow = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow();
if(isWindows10){
  try{
    lockSystem();
  }catch{
    //return an error
  }
}
mainWindow.restore();
mainWindow.focus();
mainWindow.setKiosk(true);
```

*And if you're wondering about the fact that UWP apps can get rendered on top of the lock screen, yes they indeed can get rendered on top of the lock screen. You can try to take an exam on [exam.net](https://exam.net) on a windows 10 device, and choose the restricted mode. This will result in chrome opening a pop-up window that asks you to run a UWP app that will lock the device and get rendered on top of the lock screen.*

*https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-store-guide - This won't help, as the app doesn't gain access to UWP APIs/features.*

***EDIT:*** *https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-uwp-background - Never mind, it is possible to access those features. But I can't figure out how to do it. Any idea?*

Comment: "How can I achieve that using electron/NodeJS?" - you can't... at least not directly. It's an exclusive feature of UWP until Microsoft opens-up more Windows features to non-UWP applications. As a workaround you could include a UWP executable in your Electron package and invoke that UWP program from your Electron app - which is how most Electron applications get UWP features.

Comment: Also, have you seen this? https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-store-guide

Comment: @Dai, could you please explain more about that?

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-store-guide
@Dai, yes. This won't help. It doesn't give the program access to UWP APIs/features. It only contains the win32 program inside a UWP container.